# Ethtool not changing Subsystem-ID for Intel X550T

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

I was able to changed SUBID's of intel X540AT in the past using ethtool without problems, but now that I'm moving to a board with a X550T when I use the code (modified for the desired device ID):

```
sudo ethtool -E enp2s0f0 magic 0x15638086 offset 0x242 value 0x0a
sudo ethtool -E enp2s0f0 magic 0x15638086 offset 0x243 value 0x00
sudo ethtool -E enp2s0f1 magic 0x15638086 offset 0x242 value 0x0a
sudo ethtool -E enp2s0f1 magic 0x15638086 offset 0x243 value 0x00
```

Ethtool does nothing, as soon as I restart it is back to 0x0e... Has anyone got any idea why this would be?

In case you are wondering, I'm doing this to be able to load a specific driver from another vendor in order to enable the X550T on a Unix environment (macOS-Hackintosh), the only requirement is to have Subsystem-ID 0x0a (the card has 0x0e). Perhaps the code is wrong? Someone suggested modifying the driver instead, but I have no idea how to do that honestly.

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can backup the existing firmware, change the values and bring it back via STDIN. The documentation says:

> -E --change-eeprom If value is specified, changes EEPROM byte for the specified network device. offset and value specify which byte and it's new value. **If value is not specified, stdin is read and written to the EEPROM.** The length and offset parameters allow writing to certain portions of the EEPROM. Because of the persistent nature of writing to the EEPROM, a device-specific magic key must be specified to prevent the accidental writing to the EEPROM.